# GCP set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

Tags: google-cloud-platform

i am trying to create a twitter bot to automate tweeting. i will be running my application with Google Cloud Platform, with Cloud Run, Cloud Scheduler and Cloud Storage. I am having trouble trying to run the program. The code used to work when i do not have the quotes in a separate file. Can anyone point me in the right direction or tell me if i am doing anything wrong or missing anything? the error can be found below. i have all the necessary files before i run "gcloud run deploy". i have surrealism.json and keyhole.json in my cloud storage bucket.

the work flow is as follows: google cloud scheduler execute the cloud run program when the times comes. cloud run retrieves the information in keyhole.json and allow the code to run. surrealism.json file contains the tweets that is to be tweeted. do let me know if i have misinterpreted anything. tia

```
google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
```

```
import random
import tweepy
import json
import os
from google.cloud import storage

# Download service account key file from Google Cloud Storage
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.bucket('rich_peoples_thing')
blob = bucket.blob('keyfile.json')
key_data = blob.download_as_string()

# Load key data as JSON
key_dict = json.loads(key_data)

# Set environment variable for credentials
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = json.dumps(key_dict)

# Download quotes file from Google Cloud Storage
blob = bucket.blob('surrealism.json')
quotes_data = blob.download_as_string()

# Decode JSON data
quotes = json.loads(quotes_data)

# Authenticate with Twitter API
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(api_key, api_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

# Check if the list of quotes has already been tweeted
if not quotes:
    api.update_status('Phase 1 completed')
else:
    # Choose a random quote
    quote = random.choice(quotes)

    # Post the quote as a new tweet
    api.update_status(quote)

    # Remove the tweeted quote from the list
    quotes.remove(quote)

    # Encode quotes data as JSON
    quotes_data = json.dumps(quotes)

    # Upload updated quotes file to Google Cloud Storage
    blob.upload_from_string(quotes_data)
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to read a blob from GCS to get the credentials from, how is that supposed to work? The GCS blob download needs credentials too...

Comment: In general, on Google infrastructure (GCE, GAE, Cloud Run, ...) you should just use application default credentials and for local testing, you can run `gcloud auth login` to store local credentials.

Comment: ok, but how do i use application default credentials when everything is online?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/application-default-credentials. When running on a service, you want what is described in the section [The attached service account](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/application-default-credentials#attached-sa) and for local experimentation the section [User credentials provided by using the gcloud CLI](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/application-default-credentials#personal)

Comment: If the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS isn't set, ADC uses the service account that is attached to the resource that is running your code. Please let me know if there is a different service account you are using. Can you please check the credentials for that service account, and ensure that it has access to the resources required.

Comment: If the above comment does not provide a solution for you.  For example, if you are using the **google-auth-library-python library** you may wish to try **increasing the GCE_METADATA_TIMEOUT variable to a higher value**, as this has caused issues for other customers in the past who have experienced a similar error message. You may also want to implement retry logic within your code, as this may be caused by too many requests overloading the metadata server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you all for your response. i found success by following the guide below.

```
import random
import tweepy
import json
from google.cloud import storage

# Download quotes file from Google Cloud Storage
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.bucket('bucket-name')
blob = bucket.blob('surrealism.json')
quotes_data = blob.download_as_string()

# Decode JSON data
quotes = json.loads(quotes_data)

# Authenticate with Twitter API
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(api_key, api_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

# Check if the list of quotes has already been tweeted
if not quotes:
    api.update_status('Phase 1 completed')
else:
    # Choose a random quote
    quote = random.choice(quotes)

    # Post the quote as a new tweet
    api.update_status(quote)

    # Remove the tweeted quote from the list
    quotes.remove(quote)

    # Encode quotes data as JSON
    quotes_data = json.dumps(quotes)

    # Upload updated quotes file to Google Cloud Storage
    blob.upload_from_string(quotes_data)
```

To implement the code, follow the steps below:

1. Make sure you have a Google Cloud Platform account and a project created.
2. Create a Cloud Storage bucket to store the `surrealism.json` file.
3. Upload the `surrealism.json` file to the Cloud Storage bucket.
4. Create a service account and download its key file in JSON format.
5. Grant the service account permissions to access the Cloud Storage bucket.
6. Deploy a containerized version of the code to Cloud Run.
7. Create a Cloud Scheduler job to trigger the Cloud Run service at a specific interval.

Here are the steps in more detail:

1. Go to the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) and create a new project, or use an existing one.
2. Create a Cloud Storage bucket by clicking on the Navigation menu, selecting **Storage > Browser**, and then clicking on the **Create bucket** button. Give the bucket a name and choose the location where you want it to be stored.
3. Upload the `surrealism.json` file to the bucket by clicking on the bucket name, then clicking on the **Upload files** button. Select the `surrealism.json` file from your local machine and upload it.
4. Create a new service account by clicking on the Navigation menu, selecting **IAM & Admin > Service Accounts**, and then clicking on the **Create Service Account** button. Give the service account a name and a description, and then click on the **Create** button.
5. After creating the service account, click on the **Add Key** button and select **JSON** as the key type. Download the key file and save it somewhere on your local machine.
6. Grant the service account permissions to access the Cloud Storage bucket by clicking on the bucket name, then clicking on the **Add Members** button. Enter the email address of the service account and grant it the **Storage Object Viewer** and **Storage Object Creator** roles.
7. Copy the code you provided into a Python file and make sure you replace the following variables with your own values:

   - `api_key`
   - `api_secret`
   - `access_token`
   - `access_token_secret`
   - `bucket-name` (the name of your Cloud Storage bucket)
   - `surrealism.json` (the name of your JSON file in the bucket)
8. Build and deploy a containerized version of the code to Cloud Run by following the instructions in the [Cloud Run Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy) guide.
9. After deploying the code to Cloud Run, create a Cloud Scheduler job by clicking on the Navigation menu, selecting **Tools > Cloud Scheduler**, and then clicking on the **Create job** button. Give the job a name and a description, and then set the following fields:

   - **Frequency**: select how often you want the job to run (e.g., every hour, every day, etc.).
   - **Timezone**: select the timezone in which you want the job to run.
   - **Target**: select **HTTP** and enter the URL of the Cloud Run service.
   - **HTTP method**: select **POST**.
   - **Body**: leave this field empty.
   - **Headers**: leave this field empty.
   - **Enable retries**: select **Off**.
   - **Enable job**: make sure this checkbox is selected.
10. Click on the **Create** button to create the job. The job will now run at the interval you specified, triggering the Cloud Run service, which will in turn download the `surrealism.json` file from the Cloud Storage bucket, choose a tweet from a random quote in the file, and update the file with the tweeted quote removed.

To confirm that the job is running successfully, you can check the logs of the Cloud Run service for any errors or messages. You can also check the Twitter account to see if the tweets are being posted as expected.

If you want to modify the code or the interval at which the job runs, you can edit the Cloud Run service or the Cloud Scheduler job accordingly.